# PowerShell module list different between PowerShell terminal and C# program

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am trying to use the `MSOnline` module in PowerShell in my C# application. When I run `Get-Module -ListAvailable` from within a PowerShell terminal, I can see `MSOnline` in the list of modules. However, if I run that same command from within my C# application, `MSOnline` is not one of the modules listed.

My `PSModulePath` environment variable does contain the path to the MSOnline module, `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`. Also, I am running the following code and inspecting the `results` variable, which does not have the module.

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript("Get-Module -ListAvailable");
var results = ps.Invoke();
```

Can anyone explain why the application is not seeing the module, and what I can do to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the vast majority of cases the module is registered or only works for either 32-bit or 64-bit PowerShell.  How are you compiling your C# program? If it is AnyCPU it is likely running 64-bit and won't see 32-bit only modules.  Try switching your C# program between x86 and x64 and see which one can find the module.